# Invalid date value in csv file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, powershell, csv

I export data in csv format from sql server database. It contain 5 column. one column have date and time value. When i checked the date -time value i found date time value is in wrong format. I add the filter but filter not applied on some data. I try to format the data in same format but formatting did not applied on the data. I tried everything to fix the issue but it is not getting fix.

I have attached the sample data please check it from your end.

```
7/12/2013 14:50
8/12/2013 20:14
9/12/2013 11:38
10/12/2013 15:31
13/12/2013  12:45:50
13/12/2013  14:35:42
13/12/2013  14:37:40
14/12/2013  17:00:10
18/12/2013  14:57:35
```

Data started from 13/12/2013 12:45:50 are not getting change in date time format.

If you copy the above data and paste it in excel then fix the format of data. It is not getting fix.

### I have found one interesting thing in the data. if the first value is greater then 12 then filter or formatting not applying on the data. If it is less then 12 then i can format the data.

Comment: Why don't you just exort data again and change the format of the date?

Comment: I cannot change the export format because it is hard coded in application. I have to change the data in csv file.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/710127/76571

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Excel Treating US dates as UK dates?](http://superuser.com/questions/408432/how-to-stop-excel-treating-us-dates-as-uk-dates)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the format in Region and language.

*Control Panel - Region and language - Format - date and time formats*.

I changed the short date and long date format.